# How to convert xml to java

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling

i am trying to convert from xml file to java, i have no experiance with that. So can some one please help me with it.
this is my book class below.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name= "book")
public class book {

private String ID;
private String title;
private String author;
private String genre;
private String price;
private String publicationDate;
private String discription;



public book(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g ){
    ID = a;
    title = b;
    author = c;
    genre =  d;
    price = e;
    publicationDate = f;
    discription = g;
}
@XmlElement
public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String iD) {
    ID = iD;
}
@XmlElement
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
@XmlElement
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}
@XmlElement
public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}
@XmlElement
public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
@XmlElement
public String getPublicationDate() {
    return publicationDate;
}

public void setPublicationDate(String publicationDate) {
    this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
}
@XmlElement
public String getDiscription() {
    return discription;
}

public void setDiscription(String discription) {
    this.discription = discription;
   }

}
```

now i want to convert the xml file into java objects the xml file i will attach bellow.`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <catalog>
    <book id="1">
       <author>Isaac Asimov</author>
       <title>Foundation</title>
       <genre>Science Ficition</genre>
       <price>164</price>
       <publish_date>1951-08-21</publish_date>
       <description>Excellent.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="2">
       <author>Isaac Asimov</author>
       <title>Foundation and Empire</title>
       <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
       <price>79</price>
       <publish_date>1952-10-12</publish_date>
       <description>Good.</description>
     </book>
 </catalog>
```

so far i tried to convert and read the xml file by creating the method bellow in my man class

```
enter code here
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void unma() throws JAXBException {
         JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(book.class);
         Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
         book b = (book) um.unmarshal(new File("src/Dv600/books.xml"));
         System.out.println("information");
         System.out.println("id" + b.getID());
         System.out.println("Author" + b.getAuthor());
         System.out.println("description" + b.getDiscription());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

            unma();
    }

 }
```

Comment: its not working it gives me the error. but i think i did not convert it properly i want to convert this xml file to java objects.

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: You need to post the exception so we can see what has gone wrong. But my first guess would be that it can't find your XML file in this statement `new File("src/Dv600/books.xml")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code.

1. `@XMLAttribute` is the correct annotation for id as as per your xml ID
   is an attribute of book not an element as author or description.
2. `@XMLElement` should be on the setter method not on the getter method
3. Not sure why you have a constructor in book.java, remove that as well.
4. What is Catalog, there is no need for that. I  have attached the working code please let me know if you have any questions.

************** TEST.java************
    import java.io.File;

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Test {

    public static void unma() throws JAXBException {
         JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Books.class);
         Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
         Books b = (Books) um.unmarshal(new File("c:/tester/books.xml"));

         for (int i =0;i<b.getBooks().size();i++) {
         Book bb =   b.getBooks().get(i);
         System.out.println(bb.getAuthor());
         System.out.println(bb.getTitle());
         System.out.println(bb.getDescription());
         System.out.println(bb.getGenre());
         System.out.println(bb.getPrice());
         System.out.println(bb.getDate());

         }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

            unma();
    }

 }
```

**********Books.java**********

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Books")
public class Books {

    List<Book> books;

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    @XmlElement( name = "Book" ) 
    public void setBooks( List<Book> books ) 
    { 

        this.books = books; 

    } 

}
```

*************Book.java********

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType( propOrder = { "author", "description","title", "genre","price", "date"} )
@XmlRootElement( name = "Book" )
public class Book
{
    String author;
    String description;
    String title;
    String genre;
    String price;
    String date;

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    @XmlElement( name = "author" )
    public void setAuthor( String author )
    {
        this.author = author;
    }



    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @XmlElement( name = "description" )
    public void setDescription( String description )
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @XmlElement( name = "title" )
    public void setTitle( String title )
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    @XmlElement( name = "genre" )
    public void setGenre( String genre )
    {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @XmlElement( name = "price" )
    public void setPrice( String price )
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @XmlElement( name = "date" )
    public void setDate( String date )
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

**xml for book****

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Books>
    <Book id="1">
       <author>Isaac Asimov</author>
       <title>Foundation</title>
       <genre>Science Ficition</genre>
       <price>164</price>
       <date>1951-08-21</date>
       <description>Excellent.</description>
    </Book>
    <Book id="2">
       <author>Isaac Asimov</author>
       <title>Foundation and Empire</title>
       <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
       <price>79</price>
       <date>1952-10-12</date>
       <description>Good.</description>
     </Book>

 </Books>
```

Comment: Trying to format the answer, would appreciate if any experienced person  does that for me.

Comment: Thank you so much @peeskillet.

Comment: thank you so much for kind response. i tried exact your code but unfortunatly its not working i think its problem with my file or something, but than i copied your xml file and run it it gave me this error,                   Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"book"). Expected elements are <{}book1>
 at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
 at

Comment: Did you make any changes to the xml that I provided. did you add additional book. Just keep one book structure and see if it works. In the mean time I will try on my side

Comment: no i did not change anything at all, i tried to make it work at first place than i will check further but its not working

Comment: Please see the updated code.. Also added a new object Books.

Comment: yes it works fine. but when i want to add more fields instead of just name its not working i don't know i am trying but not succeed yet.

Comment: Will add more fields to it and provide you an updated copy of it in some time

Comment: ok thanks! bkz my xml file needs to provide (id, author, title, genre, price, publish_date, description) so don't know how to provide the fields

Comment: Will use your fields

Comment: Updated Test.java and Book.java and book.xml. Please take all the code and try.

Comment: Also please use date instead of publich_date in your xml.